# working with floats mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i am customizing a **Word Press** plugin named **Gravity Forms**, now the plugin is using a column as datatype **float**

now i created a totally new interface for displaying the details of an entry that is submitted, i have a set of checkboxes in the form, what **Gravity Forms** is doing it is adding the **field_number** as a floats and then the value against it

now for one set of checboxes on my form it is using the **field_number** as **2** now the **2** remains constants no matter how many checkboxes are selected, and after that comes some points values e.g  2.1 for a specific value and then 2.2 for a specific value and so on upto n times depending on the numbers of checkboxes in the form. please see the below image for more clarification!

[image]

Important Note! i cant change the datatype of **float** as something else e.g **vahrchar** or **decimal** it totally messes up the plugin

now i did struggled with getting the float values, because **float** are not that reliable and easy to use i have seen other blogs where people prefer **double** or **decimal** over it

my main problem was this query,

```
SELECT value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE lead_id=".absint( $lead['id'] )." and field_number=2.4
```

now running this query i did not get any result, so what i did is modified my query and passed the value as decimal!

```
SELECT value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE lead_id=".absint( $lead['id'] )." and CAST(field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(2 AS DECIMAL)
```

now this query worked just fine and returned the number of rows, but the problem is it is missing some data and not returning all data. like if i have 5 rows as you can see the in the image above its returns only three rows and skips the two rows! any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want compare with 2 could be you need  a truncate instead of a cast eg:

```
SELECT value 
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail 
WHERE lead_id=".absint( $lead['id'] )." 
    and truncate(field_number,0) = 2
```

Comment: thats perfect! wish i cold buy you beer for that!, keep up the good work bro.

Comment: @uneebmeer  .. many thanks  ..  ok for the beer .. as if you had done it